# How to sort files with similar filenames into discrete folders?

Tags: applescript

I borrowed the code below from this thread: [How to sort files with similar filenames into discrete folders? (AppleScript)](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250404796?login=true)

But I would like to take it a step further for situations like this:

FROM:

- VD010234.mp4
- VD010235.mp4
- VD020234.mp4
- VD020235.mp4
- VD030234.mp4
- VD030235.mp4

TO:

01234 (Folder)

- VD010234.mp4
- VD020234.mp4
- VD030234.mp4

01235 (Folder)

- VD010235.mp4
- VD020235.mp4
- VD030235.mp4

In essence only looking at a part of the file name, in the above case, 234 and 235, and finding all files with that reference and putting them in titled folders.

```
    set DELIM to {".mp4", ".", ":"}
    
    tell application "Finder"
        -- assumption: selection is a Finder selected containing folder of the items
        set selected to selection
        set current_folder to (first item of selected) as text as alias
        set mlist to (sort (every item of folder current_folder) by name) as alias list
        
        set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, DELIM}
        if mlist is {} then return
        repeat with this_file in mlist
            -- the DELIM guarantees that this item is the basename without extension
            set basename to text item -2 of (this_file as text)
            -- avoids duplicate folder name collisions
            if not (exists folder ((current_folder as text) & basename)) is true then
                set new_folder to make new folder at current_folder with properties {name:basename}
            end if
            move (this_file as text) to new_folder
        end repeat
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID
    end tell
```

Comment: Thank you, edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Revision:**

```
set DELIM to {".mp4", ".", ":"}
tell application "Finder"
    -- assumption: selection is a Finder selected containing folder of the items
    set selected to selection
    set current_folder to (first item of selected) as text
    set mList to (every item of folder current_folder whose name ends with "mp4")
    
    set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, DELIM}
    if mList is {} then return
    repeat with this_file in mList
        set basename to text -1 thru -3 of text item -2 of (this_file as text) -- last 3 char of name
        set that_folder to (current_folder as text) & basename -- use above for folder name
        
        try
            move this_file to that_folder -- if folder exists then move
        on error number -10000 -- if not, make folder, then move
            set that_folder to make new folder at current_folder with properties {name:basename}
            move this_file to that_folder
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID
```

Instead of using the entire file name, this takes the last three characters of each filename (e.g. 234, 235) and uses those to create the folders and select which files get moved into them.

The original script sorted every file by name and then processed each file in an order that matched the destination folders (i.e. it created a folder, processed all matching files, created another folder, etc…). Using only the name's last few characters breaks that order. This version adds the step of determining each file's destination independently, and removes the sort which now has no value and probably slows things down a bit.

Two things to note about this script:

- If your file name has a period in it then your delimiters will fail in their guarantee
- I added a filter to process only mp4 files

Comment: your edit to my script does something, but on a large list i tried it on, it went awry. https://ibb.co/TbnxVMx It missed a lot of files and then for some reason put all the 2nd 3rd and 4th files of each series in one folder with 235. it looks like its processing the first video in each series and then whatever is left over just shoves it in the last first video – 


Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm… that is basically what it's doing. It moves each file to 'new_folder' but it only changes that variable when it makes a new folder. In your example, it only does that twice —for the first two files— so every file thereafter goes into the last folder created. It should be relatively simple to fix.

Comment: Thank you, this script is what i wanted!